# Eror, camera locked on an axis in mobile

Tags: aframe

I hope you have an excellent day, it happens that in desktop mode it works perfectly but on mobile devices it only moves on a single axis and also does not detect gyroscopic sensors, the same thing happens in the latest version 1.0.4, which can it be and how can I solve it?

I was checking and not only happens with me, but also with all the examples from the official website and other people's recent projects...

Edit: I found the solution thanks to the first answer, if someone else has the same problem add the following code,

```
AFRAME.components["look-controls"].Component.prototype.onTouchMove = function (t) {
                    var PI_2 = Math.PI/2,
                    e,
                    o = this.el.sceneEl.canvas,
                    i = this.yawObject,
                    j = this.pitchObject;
                    this.touchStarted && this.data.touchEnabled && (e = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageX - this.touchStart.x) / o.clientWidth, f = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / o.clientHeight, j.rotation.x += .3 * f, i.rotation.y += .5 * e, j.rotation.x = Math.max(-PI_2, Math.min(PI_2, j.rotation.x)), this.touchStart = {
                            x: t.touches[0].pageX,
                            y: t.touches[0].pageY
                        })
                    }
```

Comment: It works for me on Pixel 3. Make sure your browser is on mobile mode, not desktop. Touch panning limited to y-axis is a design decision to keep virtual and real horizon always aligned.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, that's my problem, how can I make the view free as in previous versions? I worked with Aframe several years ago and I didn't have that before.

Answer (score 0):

```
AFRAME.components["look-controls"].Component.prototype.onTouchMove = function (t) {
                var PI_2 = Math.PI/2,
                e,
                o = this.el.sceneEl.canvas,
                i = this.yawObject,
                j = this.pitchObject;
                this.touchStarted && this.data.touchEnabled && (e = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageX - this.touchStart.x) / o.clientWidth, f = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / o.clientHeight, j.rotation.x += .3 * f, i.rotation.y += .5 * e, j.rotation.x = Math.max(-PI_2, Math.min(PI_2, j.rotation.x)), this.touchStart = {
                        x: t.touches[0].pageX,
                        y: t.touches[0].pageY
                    })
                }
```